# How to calculate time of travel between 2 cities?

Tags: java, android

I have following task: to calculate time of travel between 2 cities using any api or services. But I haven't made it before, and I have 2 ideas: calculate time using speed limit on roads or trafic flow. Are there means to help me with my task? May be Google Maps are able to help me? Thank you, anyway.

Additional: I don't have a speed of transport.

Comment: Possible duplicate....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042885/using-google-maps-api-to-get-travel-time-data

Comment: The only reason I'm not flagging this as a duplicate is because it's not an *exact* duplicate. It's in the same ballpark and is definitely more broad (cover potentially more engines), but still not the same. Theoretically, it could be solved by other map APIs (the other question addresses GMaps). Of course, we all know GMaps seems to be the first choice, but still... probably "lack of research" instead.

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps API will do this. A simple google search returns many examples.

dead link removed.

Comment: But this example demonstrate how to calculate distance between points, not time!

Comment: The point of my answer was that you should google your question and you will find an answer.

Comment: For instance the SO link above.

Comment: Yep, google and research your answer. Buy n' Large isn't your superstore!