# Swift: Get travel time between two location using Google Maps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

I have an app that uses Google Maps and I want to get the travel time between my current location and another location. How will I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CLLocation to calculate the distance between two locations. Something like,

`CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];`

Once you calculated the distance, then you can easily calculate the travel time by using the speed distance time formula

`i.e.,  speed = distance / time`

since you know the distance and if you assume the speed, you can calculate  time taken for the travel as

`time = distance / speed`

Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042885/using-google-maps-api-to-get-travel-time-data) to use Google Maps API to calculate the time travel.

Comment: Is there something I can use in Google Maps API that will automatically calculate the travel time?

Comment: check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042885/using-google-maps-api-to-get-travel-time-data)