# Calculate the estimated travel time Google Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

How can I calculate the estimated travel time on a route with react and google-maps?

Comment: Any advice to guide me?

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042885/using-google-maps-api-to-get-travel-time-data) . I believe this will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want : [Distance Matrix Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixRequests)

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I'm in Cuba and Google Developers is blocked.