# React Native: Is it possible to get drive time between 2 locations using google map api

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps and I would like to get the travel time provided by Google maps between my current location and another location. The answers I have seen on StackOverflow are in violation of Google policy. [Swift: Get travel time between two locations using Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042885/using-google-maps-api-to-get-travel-time-data)
  and [Using Google Maps API to get travel time data [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042885/using-google-maps-api-to-get-travel-time-data)

Comment: What is wrong with creating a directions object, load waypoints, await 'load', then get the duration from the response, as in the link you shared.

Comment: @ZenBoat I didn't read all the comments and the proposed new soluting below the approved answer. I will implement and update the question.